# Cannot restrict direct access to views and functions in Codeigniter using basepath

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to stop direct access to controller functions or views in Codeigniter for that i am using following code, I have seen other similar links on stackoverflow but they are not working, i am able to load the view by hitting url:

> Controller: abc.php

```
<?php 

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Abc extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
  }

  public function Create_Course() {
     $this->load->view('abc');
  }
}

?>
```

> View: abc.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ABC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Whatever</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. You are *completely wrong*. We newer use this in view

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
```

Every one can see your **`controller/method`**(`abc/Create_Course`
) name but ***no one knows about your view name*** without viewing your project. So there is no any purpose to hide or restrict view from others.

There is no way to access view folder from URL. if assume some how some one access this then also no one knows your folder names. so this warning message shows in browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abdulla. But when i place basepath in controller it does not restrict direct access to controller function.

Comment: restrict what?? what is your purpose

Comment: i want to restrict user from viewing page by directly hitting url.

Comment: So setup logging to this. then no one can access this without logging to system. That's my best opinion too

Comment: So what is the purpose of basepath?

Comment: that's to protect your files from malicious access and scripts. [check this link](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61042.html)

Comment: Thanks Abdulla. Can u give me link of logging system to use in my project because i am new to codeigniter

Comment: This is one of best [tutorial for login](http://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/) i recommended for you.

Comment: @user3653474 happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Per Codeigniters documentation you need to put an underscore before the function name in your controller, like this:

```
private function _utility()
{
  // some code
}
```

This is perfect for custom rules for say form validation or anything else you want in the controller but not available via the browser url. Which I think is what you are looking for.